# Creating shortcuts on OS X without using mouse

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Say I have a file under /var and I want to make its shortcut on desktop without using the mouse. Is that possible? I really want to use the trackpad as little as possible since I don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are just symlinks, so `ln -s` will do it.

```
ln -s /var/whatever ~/Desktop
```

Comment: Not true for files. Both are treated the same in Finder, so from a user perspective it makes no difference. But try making an alias in Finder and `ls -l` the directory, it's not a symlink.